# Python: Ask user to enter 5 different marks

Tags: python, dictionary

The question is Write a program that asks the user to enter 5 different students and their mark out of 100. If the user tries to enter a student twice, the program should detect this and ask them to enter a unique student name (and their mark).

my program is..

```
dictionary = {}

count = 0

while count < 5:
   name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
   mark = input("Enter your mark out of 100: ")
   if name not in dictionary:
       dictionary[name] = mark
       count = count + 1
   else:
       name = raw_input("Enter a unique name: ")
       mark = input("Enter the mark out of 100: ")
       if name not in dictionary:
          dictionary[name] = mark
          count = count + 1

print dictionary
```

my problem is how do you loop the else: code if the user keeps entering the same name and mark?

Comment: General comment: Testing if "Mike" is in the dictionary will not return true if "mike" is in the dictionary. You should store a lower/upper case version of the name, and then match a lower / upper case input to see if it already exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = {}
count = 0
while count < 5:
   name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
   name = name.strip().lower() # store name in lower case, e.g. aamir and Aamir consider duplicate
   if not dictionary.get(name):
       mark = input("Enter your mark out of 100: ")
       dictionary[name] = mark
       count += 1
   else:
       print "please enter unique name"

print dictionary
```

- Store name in lowercase so that `aamir` and `Aamir` both should be consider duplicate
- the duplicate check should be performed earlier than step `Enter your mark` to save one step for end user

Answer (score 1):

You mix `input` and `raw_input`, that's a bad thing. Usually you use `raw_input` in Python 2 and `input` in Python 3. The quick and dirty way to solve your problem is:

```
dictionary = {}

count = 0

while count < 5:
   name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
   mark = raw_input("Enter your mark out of 100: ")
   if name not in dictionary:
       dictionary[name] = mark
       count = count + 1
   else:
       print("You already used that name, enter an unique name.")

print dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you  only need todo this:

```
dictionary = {}

count = 0

while count < 5:
      name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
      mark = input("Enter your mark out of 100: ")
      if name not in dictionary:
          dictionary[name] = mark
          count = count + 1

 print dictionary
```